# Use WMI to create IIS Application Directory with C#

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, wmi

We have a web application that is installed on Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 systems. In the past, our install code used ADSI to create a couple of application directories in IIS, but this requires the IIS 6 management components to be installed in Windows 2008. I have been trying to use WMI to create the application directories so we can support both operating systems.

I have been trying this code

```
   public static void AddVirtualFolder(string serverName, string websiteId, string name, string path)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\MicrosoftIISV2", serverName));
        scope.Connect();

        string siteName = string.Format("W3SVC/{0}/Root/{1}", websiteId, name);

        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("IIsWebVirtualDirSetting"), null);
        ManagementObject oWebVirtDir = mc.CreateInstance();

        oWebVirtDir.Properties["Name"].Value = siteName;
        oWebVirtDir.Properties["Path"].Value = path;
        oWebVirtDir.Properties["AuthFlags"].Value = 5; // Integrated Windows Auth.
        oWebVirtDir.Properties["EnableDefaultDoc"].Value = true;
        // date, time, size, extension, longdate ;
        oWebVirtDir.Properties["DirBrowseFlags"].Value = 0x4000003E;
        oWebVirtDir.Properties["AccessFlags"].Value = 513; // read script 
        oWebVirtDir.Put();

        ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(scope, new System.Management.ManagementPath("IIsWebVirtualDir='" + siteName + "'"), null);
        ManagementBaseObject inputParameters = mo.GetMethodParameters("AppCreate2");
        inputParameters["AppMode"] = 2;
        mo.InvokeMethod("AppCreate2", inputParameters, null);
        mo = new ManagementObject(scope, new System.Management.ManagementPath("IIsWebVirtualDirSetting='" + siteName + "'"), null);
        mo.Properties["AppFriendlyName"].Value = name;
        mo.Put();
    }
}
```

However, I get path not found errors on known directories. If anybody has some references I can use, I would greatly appreciate it. Any other suggestions on how to go about this are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the code above, you will still need the IIS6 compatibility bits on Windows 2008/IIS7. The reason for this is that the calls to set properties such as `DirBrowseFlags`, `AccessFlags` and so on are IIS 6 metabase properties that are not supported in IIS7 without the IIS6 management components.

For IIS7 I'd recommend programming directly against the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace, but if you really need to use WMI then see this article:

> [Managing Sites with IIS 7.0's WMI Provider (IIS.NET)](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/162/managing-sites-with-iis-7039s-wmi-provider/)

Comment: I had hoped to be able to use a single code path for either IIS6 or IIS7, so I had avoided using the IIS7 specific Microsoft.Web.Administration classes. However, I guess that I will just have to detect the IIS version and continue using ADSI for IIS6 and use the new stuff in another code path for IIS7.

Thanks,

Comment: @Shane - another good reason is that the IIS6 compat shim also bodges the `HandlerMappings` (analogous to IIS6 scriptmaps) with `AboCustomMapper` objects which can't take advantage of features such as launch pre-conditions. Trust me, the effort is worth it to maintain good `applicationHost.config` file hygiene.

Comment: I don't quite understand your recommendation to use Web.Administration because Microsoft.Web.Administation can only admister to/from IIS7+ servers. Are we assuming IIS7?